# Was Missy lying?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of *Death in Heaven* The Doctor claims to have found Gallifrey - however he also says “Never trust a hug, it's just a way to hide your face,” and we know that Clara is lying to him.

Has he actually found Gallifrey were “Missy” indicated it would be or is he simply pretending so that Clara thinks he has somewhere to go and can stay with (he believes) Danny?

The fact we don't actually Gallifrey but do see him smashing the console makes me think the red planet is still Gallifrey there… somewhere….

Comment: I always rather thought she DIDN'T lie; but the Doctor is missing some detail. (The planet is out of phase with the rest of the universe, it's cloaked so as to not start a new war, the whole planet is in a pocket dimension who's entry is there.. something.)  Then, later, Either the Master/Missy or a message from him/her will mock the Doctor for 'Missing the Obvious.'  A clear lie like that is just to simple and easy for the Master's character to enjoy.

Comment: She may have lied about the location, but Missy probably did know where Gallifrey was, since the Master should have been there when it was put into the "pocket universe" in "The Day of the Doctor" (the Master was last seen going back to Gallifrey at the tail end of the Time War along with Rassilon and co. in "The End of Time"), and Missy's later dialogue suggested that saving Gallifrey had saved her as well, implying she then found a way to escape the pocket universe. See my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72981/22250), along with the comments on that answer, for details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

Missy lied to The Doctor about Gallifrey. We see what he sees when he goes to the coordinates that she supplied to him, and he sees empty space.

Later, The Doctor lies about Gallifrey to spare Clara the choice between him and PE (he assumes Pink has come back). Clara lies to The Doctor about Pink so that he can go back to Gallifrey without worrying about her.

[Update - January 2015]
Confirmation of the lying between The Doctor and Clara is revealed in the following dialog from the 2014 Christmas Special ("Last Christmas"):

> DOCTOR - You never told me he was dead. You said he made it back.
>
> CLARA - I lied. I lied so you'd go home to Gallifrey instead of
>   fussing about me.
>
> DOCTOR - I never found Gallifrey. I lied. So you'd stay with Danny.

Comment: Rule 1 - The Doctor Lies!

Comment: @Liath: The Doctor Who visual effects team don't tend to.

Comment: @Liath Rule #1 is actually, Steven Moffat lies. But we will only find that out after he'll have left the show.

Comment: It's the *Gift of the Magi* all over again...

Comment: Is that really why he was so angry and smashed the console? It wasn't very clear to me, and it all happened very quickly.

Comment: @MrLister: yeah Gallifrey coulda just been invisible or something.

Answer (score -1):

That is a yes and no question, The Doctor did go the the right coordinates given by Mistress/Master, but Galifrey wasn't there, so that makes most people think that Mistress/Master did lie. WRONG! Mistress/Master did give The Doctor the right coordinates, but she never told him what dimension it was in. For all we know Galifrey could be in Rose's Dimension, but a bigger question is, if Mistress/Master came back through different dimension Galifrey, wouldn't a rip in space and time happen like in season 2 where a cyberman vs dalek vs human battle was happening, or like in season 4 when Rose came back to warn the Doctor about the upcoming dalek invasion and Donna became a human time lord combination and there were 2 Doctors and 1 of them committed genicide on the daleks, we may never know, but there HAS to be closure for this in the next season where Rose comes back yet again to tell the Doctor about Galifrey and the rip in space and time or the rip between dimensions which is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: according to The Doctor, all of those problems with cross-dimensional travel were because the Time Lords and their technology were not around to stabilize things. If Gallifrey was saved, then presumably cross-dimensional travel would work much better.

Comment: Ok that does make sense but why wouldn't the Time Lords bring Galifrey back to the original place? I'm gonna guess that they didn't have the tech but idk